# SMTP works with apache 2.2/php54 but not with apache 2.4/php736

Tags: php, apache, smtp, phpmailer

The code I am running on apache2.2/php5.4 (32bit) is the exact same code I am running on apache2.4 (64bit). I am using the newest phpMailer files and like I said I am running the exact same code on both server installations. This is running on a windows 10 environment.

Here is a sample of the SMTP debug output from the apache 2.2 configuration

> 2021-04-12 16:15:53 Connection: opening to ssl://mail.erkbiz.com:465,
> timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2021-04-12 16:15:54 Connection: opened

Here is a sample of the debugger from the apache 2.4 configuration

> 2021-04-12 16:15:17 Connection: opening to ssl://mail.erkbiz.com:465,
> timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2021-04-12 16:15:17 SMTP ERROR: Failed
> to connect to server: (0)

Here is a snippet of the code used to run the mailer

```
require_once("../mt/mailerUtils/class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("../mt/mailerUtils/class.pop3.php");
require_once("../mt/mailerUtils/class.smtp.php");

class sendTextmsg
{

function sendTxt($pcname,$msg) {
    
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->isSMTP();                  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;           
$mail->Host = 'mail.erkbiz.com';  
$mail->Username = 'testsmtp@erkbiz.com';     
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';    
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                    
$mail->Port =  465;                                 
$mail->From = 'erkbiz@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'SMTP Test';
$mail->From ='erkbiz@gmail.com';'erkbiz@comcast.net';
$mail->FromName = 'erk';
```

Any suggestions as to why I am experiencing this problem are most welcomed....thank you